# why is mysql database deactivated on xampp status but green on the xampp control panel applocation?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have an issue with XAMPP 1.7.4. So far it has been doing great on windows 7 and 8, but when I tried installing it on windows xp service pack 3, it gave me a MySQL error #2002.
The BIG issue was that in the status page the MYSQL Database was noted as DEACTIVATED as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]
Meanwhile, in the XAMPP control panel application, MySQL is actually running well, even in the services tab, so what could be the problem with this set up???

[image]

[image]

Comment: since httpd.exe is running I assume you have a apache installed as a service may also has mysql running. Those can lead to ports being used by the service and xampp is getting blocked out. Try to stop both the apache and mysql service and then start xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem : MySql Status appears as deactivated.

- Ensure your my.ini file points to the correct MySql **port** (typically 3306)
- Use localhost:(Apache port number)/phpmyadmin to access the mysql user : *pma* : This user needs no password.

The second bullet is how I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i came up with an ideal solution, the xampp folder in C: was corrupted after the OS crashed, therefore there were missing files which led to re-installation of xampp but since the registry was not cleared, the application could not take control of the apache & mysql ports, i used a registry cleaner and re-installed xampp again and this time it worked from the inset. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As cptnk said, look at your poccesses list – there may be mysqld (MariaDB for ex.) service started by other stack.
So if it is launched not from your xampp stack – then stop it and run stack not from xampp-control, but with apache_start.bat and mysql_start.bat or with xampp_start.exe.