# Mysql database deactivated - Xampp v3.2.1, Windows 8

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

Yes, I know this question has been asked and answered a dozen times but I have searched and tried all that was suggested and uninstalled and reinstalled like 4 times and still haven't gotten any closer to activating mysql database. It shouldn't be deactivated.

Please help me. I wanted to post pictures which would help in visualizing what is going on but I can't so I will try my best to explain.

xampp control panel: I have apache and mysql service modules ticked.

localhost/xampp status page shows mysql database : deactivated.

localhost/phpmyadmin shows exclamation marks on the databases and 'x' on the server connection collation.

for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322550/how-to-activate-the-mysql-database-in-xampp-on-windows-platform) i did check mysql_error.log as suggested by best answer:

```
2014-08-27 11:18:44 28348 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.20 started; log sequence number 1665244
2014-08-27 11:18:44 28348 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-08-27 11:18:44 28348 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-08-27 11:18:44 28348 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-08-27 11:18:44 28348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-08-27 11:18:45 28348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-08-27 11:18:45 28348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.20'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

so port is 3306.

for the answer below the best answer i did run mysql_start.bat:

```
MySQL is trying to start
Please wait ...
MySQL is starting with mysql\bin\my.ini<console>
[Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is     
deprecated and will be removed in future release. Please use full name instead.
[Warning[ TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use 
--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option <see documentation for more details>
MySQL could not be started.
```

"MySQL could not be started"

for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469111/why-is-mysql-database-deactivated-on-xampp-status-but-green-on-the-xampp-control) i did do the second bullet but it didnt work for me. mysql database status still remianed deactivated.

I wanted to try this [blog's](http://trebleclick.blogspot.com/2009/01/xampp-mysql-deactivated-fix.html) suggestions but I couldn't find winmysqladmin.exe

I'm sorry, it must be annoying having this question pop up all the time like spam but I really need help with this. Please and thank you!

**EDIT**
if i go to 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin the exclamation marks and x is not there but 127.0.0.1/xampp/ status page still shows mysql database deactivated.
i tested ipv6: it is enabled but i don't have an address for it so i guess ipv4 is what im using. how do i bind it to ipv4 instead of ipv6? do i just disable ipv6?

Comment: Not sure if this is gong to help but you are binding to a very strange IPV6 address`::` and I cant find any information on that. Are you connecting to a IPV4 address?

Comment: huh. thats weird. i just did a test for the ipv6 connection and it said that i do not have ipv6 address. so i checked my internet properties ipv6 is checked. so is it the ipv6 that is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
Attempting to start MySQL service...
Problem detected!
Port 3306 in use by "I:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"!
MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Comment: why should this be an answer to the question?